# Non-null assertion operator required but value checked for non-null beforehand

Tags: typescript

I don't understand why the non-null assertion operator `!` is required in my callback function because I check the value in the `if` before.

The compiler fails with error `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

Of course using `!.label` works but I would like to understand why it doesn't in this case. Is that because of the "new scope" of my callback function ?

**[Live demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJTiAJsg3gWAChkTkAbOAIwjIH4AuZAZzClAHMBuIgXyKIQUmTZAGEA9gFsADuJARwefsVLSArpTLAEyShmwM0%20rN0JFSydZu3IoEOFjlkAns2gA3bSgC8yeQHdkAGUPLwAKAEpTc1UNLR1pKHEkYUilFQsSYBhkMLAAC2AmADo9TCwI9Mzq5AB6WuQCotLjYopqMmRfACJxAGtuzjqGgHVxKD6mGJrSer8IQJCoTyRI4sTkiGEAJjC07wA%20RsKSsuwAQjaqGi7kXoGo4eQxiamMmbqAKmmPppKmUJIdZJFJMXb7I4Ed4fUjZXJ-FrlSpQmEwhFnLBXDq3e6DH6o5B8aE1HhRfE1T4NOYvSbk6oIgHLLzAzY7PaVQ7HZoYrE3Hr9bqPOYAMTgwDIJWe%20VctDQEAQcDUAOQ4hyBRQAWYCHE0hQtDphJ%20RKJAiEIiWKxQUJ%20VnilhBWzBYQVZDIlEQfUYEOQ7nEwAqVRqLrdHsipgsxuUcwAsmKQAI5CxkNqZLdNRIZHIFGAwwmZIjsLcUaR2jRGN0YOJxN1eKYU9IWaDc4QgA)**

```js
interface Brand {
    label?: string;
}

class Component {

    public brand?: Brand;

    public readonly service = new Service();

    public process() {
        if (this.brand) {
            // this.brand.label = "ok"; // Works
            // this.service.process2(() => this.brand!.label = "ok"); // Works
            /*
            this.service.process2(() => {
                if (this.brand) {
                    this.brand.label = "ok";
                }
            });
            */ // Works
            this.service.process2(() => this.brand.label = "ok"); // Fails. Why ? Because of the new scope ?
        }
    }
}

class Service {

    public process2(callback: () => void) {
        callback();
    }
}

// Main
const comp = new Component();
comp.brand = {
    label: "foo"
};
comp.process();
```

*It makes my ESLint analysis to fails because I enabled the rule [`no-non-null-assertion`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-non-null-assertion.md) and I don't want to manually ignore these lines.*

Comment: When you close over `this.brand` in a function, it is unsafe to assume that the function will be invoked immediately. This means that facts that were proved to be true at the moment the closure was created might no longer be true when the code in the closure executes. Copying `this.brand` to a local variable: `if(this.brand){const brand=this.brand;/* etc */}` and closing over the local might give you what you want.

Comment: @spender Oh ok I get it now, it's because of the "async" my callback brings in. I had a hard time trying to look for documentation on this. Do you have any ?

Comment: No. I'm shooting from the hip, hence a comment rather than an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, `if (this.brand)` just guarantees that  `this.service.process2` will be called.

**But**, your `this.brand` inside the callback which you pass inside `this.service.process2` can be null or undefined when callback is called

Comment: I didn't think of this but yeah I understand now. Thanks!